# use c code from package cubature

Tags: r

What changes do I have to make to a working R package (written in C) to connect its C code with the C code of another package, in this particular case package cubature?

My attempt has been as follows:

1. In the description file I have added: `Depends: cubature (>= 1.3-11)` and `LinkingTo: cubature`
2. In the `init.c` file I have added: `#include cubature.h` and

   `pcubature_P = (int(*)(unsigned, integrand, void *, unsigned, const 
    double *, const double *, size_t, double, double, error_norm, double 
    *, double *)) R_GetCCallable("cubature","pcubature");`

where `pcubature_P` is the intended name for calling the pcubature function from the cubature package.

The error message I am getting is: error: ‘pcubature_P’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘pcubature_v’?

How can I correct this?